# Получение id заголовка по клику

Tags: jquery, javascript, css

Имеется часть кода, которая через jquery реализует "аккордеон", т.е. по клику на блоке `h4` следующий за ним блок, заключенный в параграф `p` либо сворачивается, либо разворачивается:

```
$(".accord h4").click(function(){
    $(this).next("p").slideToggle("slow").siblings("p:visible").slideUp("slow");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(this).siblings("h4").removeClass("active");
});
```

Появилась необходимость в момент щелчка еще и срисовывать `id` этого хэдера (на котором щелкнули) и прятать в переменную для дальнейшей обработки. Как это сделать? Потерялся в структуре жквери.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вроде так:
    $(this).attr("id");